# Using localizated enums on spinner

Tags: android, localization, enums, android-spinner

I want to populate a Spinner with translated/localized descriptions of an Enum. I've created the following code to achieve it:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    EnumItem1,
    EnumItem2,
    EnumItem3;

    public static final String ENUM_NAME = "MyEnum";

    public String getResourceKey() {
        return MyEnum.ENUM_NAME + this.name();
    }

    public String getLocalizedDescription(Context context) {
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        String resourceKey = getResourceKey();
        int resId = res.getIdentifier(resourceKey, "string", context.getPackageName());
        if (0 != resId) {
            return (res.getString(resId));
        }
        return (name());        
    }
}
```

When I want to populate the spinner I am calling the function:

```
private void populateMyEnumSpinner() {
    Spinner MyEnumSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMyEnum);
    MyEnum MyEnums[] = MyEnum.values();
    ArrayList<String> MyEnumList = new ArrayList<String>(MyEnums.length);

    for(MyEnum MyEnum: MyEnums) {
        MyEnumList.add(MyEnum.getLocalizedDescription(this));
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> MyEnumSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MyEnumList);
    MyEnumSpinner.setAdapter(MyEnumSpinnerAdapter);
}
```

But when I want to retrieve the selected item, I get the localized String instead of a value of MyEnum. I need a MyEnum value so I can insert a Switch(MySelectedEnumValue) block. Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I have been thinking on another solution: I can have a string-array in strings.xml and an enum with the same values/order in this string-array. What I don't like about this proposal is that is easy to add an element to the enum a forget the array, or change the order of the items and mess it all.